# ExtendedFloatingActionButton does not set the text programmatically

Tags: android

I have this FAB view in my fragment:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />
```

But when I programmatically set the text via:

```
mFab.setText("Hello");
```

It does not set the FAB's text to "Hello". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a weird solution but works. I had to add the "android:text" attribute in my layout for the java code to successfully set the text.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:text="dummy" />
```